# Jmeter json extractor random value in a set

Tags: jmeter

I would like to extract random set from JSON response

The random is working , however it doesnt return in set.

sometimes it returns key1: 123 and key2: def

which i expect, should be key1 & key2 is 123

or

key1 & key2 = def

JSON format:

```
{
    "data": {
        "set": [
            {
                "key1": "123",
                "key2": "123"
            },
            {
                "key1": "abc",
                "key2": "def"               
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]

JSON Path expression: $.data.set[*].key1;$.data.set[*].key2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JSON Extractor you will have 2 random key values.

If you want the "pair" I think you will need to go for [JSR223 Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor).

Example [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) code would be something like:

```
def set = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).data.set
def randomEntry = set.get(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0, set.size()))

vars.put('key1', randomEntry.key1)
vars.put('key2', randomEntry.key2)
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)
- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and Producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)